# Approximate Integration of slowly varying function

Tags: integration

I have an integration
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{t_1}dt\ A(t)\exp[i\phi_0(t)] \exp(i \omega_0 t)$$
where $A(t)\exp[i\phi_0(t)]$ is a slowly varying function as compared to $\exp(i \omega_0 t)$. Is there an approximation that I can take, so that this integral can be solved in a closed form?

Comment: A slowly varying function as compared to $e^{i\omega_0t}$ means that $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt}\big(A(t)e^{i\phi_0(t)}\big)\ll\omega_0$ on the interval $(-\infty;t_1]$. As we suppose that the integral converges, $ A(t)e^{i\phi_0(t)}$ is a finite function ($A(t)e^{i\phi_0(t)}\big|_{t=-\infty}=0)$, and we can try integration by part to get the asymptotic:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{t_1} A(t)e^{i\phi_0(t)} e^{i \omega_0 t}\ dt=\frac{1}{i\omega_0}A(t)e^{i\phi_0(t)}e^{i \omega_0 t}\big|_{t=-\infty}^{t_1}-\frac{1}{i\omega_0}\int_{-\infty}^{t_1} \big(A(t)e^{i\phi_0(t)}\big)' e^{i \omega_0 t}\ dt$$

Comment: $$=\frac{A(t_1)e^{i\phi_0(t_1)}e^{i \omega_0 t_1}}{i\omega_0}-\frac{1}{i\omega_0}\int_{-\infty}^{t_1} \big(A(t)e^{i\phi_0(t)}\big)' e^{i \omega_0 t}\ dt$$